# Input trigger change wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fire up an event when the barcode from the image gets captured. I am using a function which selects the first `li` from the search .

On my Js file I use this for capturing barcode that works

```
 Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {
        var code = result.codeResult.code;

    if (App.lastResult !== code) {
        App.lastResult = code;
        var $node = null, canvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.image;

        $node = $('<li><div class="thumbnail"><div class="imgWrapper"><img /></div><div class="caption"><h4 class="code"></h4></div></div></li>');
        $node.find("img").attr("src", canvas.toDataURL());
        $node.find("h4.code").html(code);


        $("#result_strip ul.thumbnails").prepend($node);
        $("#barcodescanr").val(code).focus();
        $("#barcodescanr").trigger("change");               
    }
});
```

The problem is that the following function is not executed

```
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example
var $input = $('#barcodescanr');

//on keyup, start the countdown
$input.on('change', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown
$input.on('keydown', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
  $('#ui-id-1 li:first-child').trigger('click');
  $('#registerButton').click();
  $('#barcodescanr').val('');
}
```

I have searched all the other topics but nothing seems to help

Comment: is the element #barcodescanr created dynamically ?

Comment: barcodescanr is an text input whose value is changed everytime an image gets captured